# Why cosine similarity should be used for word vectors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have been thinking on this thing a bit and wanted to take opinions/thoughts from ppl.

If you know cosine similarity makes a lot of sense for distance measure between data points when the length of vector or weights of vector terms do not need to be a distinguishing factor. For example comparing a small text to long text document using tf-idf vector would be largely skewed if we use Euclidean distance.

Cosine similarity by default normalized for the length of the document so is the right choice in those cases.

However it all makes sense when the text vector is represented by tf or tf-idf vector as the tf values of a long document would influence the Euclidean distance metric.

However if we represent a text document with word embeddings using word2vec or Glove or Fasttext of any of the word embeddings algo, then the resulting word vector is actually the weights of the neural network trained to get the embeddings.

In that case the vector weights is not signifying the length of the document or something.

Why is cosine similarity still the best measure of distance of two text then?

For ex. if we have the following points represented by word vectors of text.

[image]

Now if I want to find the class of the grey point (lowermost left) using 1 nearest neighbour, if I use lets say cosine similarity, then the 1NN for grey point would be actually the top right most red point with class adult.

However the point which is actually similar to grey is the blue point above it.

So in these cases we see cosine similarity doesn't make sense but Euclidean distance make more sense.

If these points are nothing but individual text documents represented by word embeddings, shouldn't we be using ED than cosine similarity?

So then question becomes, for text documents using word embeddings is ED the better choice for distance measure or cosine similarity?

For text documents using tf-idf we know its cosine as it normalizes for the length of document which is represented by individual term frequency

Comment: As this is not directly related to programming, but rather a theoretical question, please consider asking it on [stats.se], or [datascience.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is specific to machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You may consider visiting [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com) instead.